# How to verify the correct size of a cloned repo from GitHub?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, github-api

my question is how to verify the actual size of a cloned repository, comparing to its size on Github, to automatically check if the repo has been downloaded correctly.

The problem is that the size given by the GitHub API does not match with the size of the cloned repo.
Here's what I do:

1. I get the repository size using GitHub API

   $ echo https://github.com/jemole/drScratch | perl -ne 'print $1 if m!([^/]+/[^/]+?)(?:.git)?$!' | xargs -i curl -s -k https://api.github.com/repos/'{}' | grep size

> Output: "size": 55617,

2. I clone the repository and calculate the size of the downloaded folder

   $ git clone https: //github.com/jemole/drScratch

   $ du -s drScratch

> Output: 69104 drScratch/

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by comparing the size to the repo? git has some built-in sanity checks when checking out. If you really want to roll your own, use something more reliable like hashing the checked-out files

Comment: @wonderb0lt One could just use [git fsck](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) to validate the git data, and then just check out the known-good hash of the remote head. Guaranteed to point to the same data, barring expensive SHA1 collisions.

Comment: If you simply calculate the total size of all the files in the `.git` directory it would give you an inkling about the size of that folder on that disk. If you try to compare that to the result of doing the same operation on another clone then you need to be aware that there are many things that can be different. Packing, garbage and pruning in various stages, etc. Things like that will make a difference.

Comment: If on the other hand you only want to ensure you've gotten everything down locally then you have a couple of options: 1. trust git to work correctly. 2. Do a `git fetch` and ensure it doesn't bring in lots of new things after the clone. 3. Do a `git fsck` to verify the integrity of the clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a git repo does vary, since there is no canonical way for git to store the data (At least there are single objects vs. pack files, also pack files might be different between different repos -- just look for the size of a local git repo before and after a call to `git gc`). So you can't use the size as a measure for a correct download.

You can check your local repo with a call to `git fsck`, this command walks through all revisions and looks if each referenced object conforms to its hash.